# Как переключаться между несколькими targets в одном приложении

Tags: swift, xcode

Как переключаться между несколькими targets в одном приложении, если нет единой кодовой базы? Пробовал использовать storyboard reference и выбрал оба targets в target membership, но мне выдают ошибку command linkStoryboards failed with nonzero exit code

Comment: вопрос не вполне понятен, что значит переключаться в данном случае?

Comment: @schmidt9, нажимаешь на одну кнопку - всплывает окно одного таргета, на другую - другого

Comment: Все нужные файлы выбираются перед сборкой в targets membership и всё

Comment: @schmidt9, я забыл выбрать второй storyboard в target membership. Все работает. Спасибо